# MySql get list of pages by user_id or if user_id is not defined get all pages

Tags: php, mysql, sql, where-clause

I would like to get a list of pages from my MySQL table. But I want to get a list of pages added by all users if the $user_id value is NULL and if the $user_id value is defined I need to get a list of pages added by that particular user. I feel like there may be a simple solution for this, but I have tried to find a solution for this kind of situation for a long time and I failed with approaches such as "WHERE user_id is NOT NULL OR user_id = $user_id". How do I need to modify the below code to obtain expected results?

```
public function getPagesList($user_id = NULL){

  $this->db->query ('
    SELECT `page_id`, `page_name`
    FROM `pages`
    WHERE `user_id` = :user_id

');

$this->db->bind(':user_id', $user_id);

return $this->db->resultSet();
}
```

Comment: Why not check the $user_id is null and change the query before executing the MySQL query? Depending on the size of your database I'd recommend checking you have sufficient indexes on fields that you're using in where clauses to ensure it's speedy. Just make sure you don't have indexes on >40% of your MySQL columns. You might also want to stick a limit on the MySQL query and paginate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to get a list of pages added by all users if the $user_id value is NULL and if the $user_id value is defined I need to get a list of pages added by that particular user.

This would translate as:

```
WHERE :user_id is NULL OR user_id = :user_id
```

When the parameter is `null`, this returns all rows; when the parameter is set, it is used for filtering column `user_id`.

You can shorten the expression a little with `coalesce()`, but it might be less efficient:

```
WHERE COALESCE(:user_id, user_id) = user_id
```

Note that, as commented by Liam Sorsby, the most efficient option is likely to check if the parameter is set from your application, and modify the query string accordingly. If the parameter is not set, the query does not have a `WHERE` clause; if it is set, then `WHERE user_id = :user_id`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a wildcard with LIKE

as Liam Sorsby pointed correctly all Pages could be a lot of pages, so you should be thinking about pagonation or Limiting the number of rows

```
public function getPagesList($user_id = NULL){
   $uid = is_null($user_id) ?  '%' : $user_id;
  $this->db->query ('
    SELECT `page_id`, `page_name`
    FROM `pages`
    WHERE `user_id` LIKE :user_id

');

$this->db->bind(':user_id', $uid);

return $this->db->resultSet();
}
```

This works like so

> ```
> create table numericstring
> ( pk INT auto_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
> , id INT
> );
> ```

> ```
> insert into numericstring (id) values
>  ( 20001 )
> ,( 20002 )
> ,( 30001 )
> ,( 30002 )
> ,( 30003 )
> ,( 30004 )
> ,( 37 )
> ,( 937 )
> ,( 21 )
> ,( 3 )
> ,( 222222 )
> ,( 3333 )
> ;
> ```

> ```
> select * from numericstring WHERE id LIKE '3'
> ```
>
> ```
> pk | id
> -: | -:
> 10 |  3
> ```

> ```
> select * from numericstring WHERE id LIKE 3
> ```
>
> ```
> pk | id
> -: | -:
> 10 |  3
> ```

> ```
> select * from numericstring WHERE id LIKE '%'
> ```
>
> ```
> pk |     id
> -: | -----:
>  1 |  20001
>  2 |  20002
>  3 |  30001
>  4 |  30002
>  5 |  30003
>  6 |  30004
>  7 |     37
>  8 |    937
>  9 |     21
> 10 |      3
> 11 | 222222
> 12 |   3333
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=29627feed697c77b32d064d40397c1b2)*

Comment: I'd personally use `=== null` over is_null as it's faster. However, it's not advised to use a LIKE query for just `%` as you're going to trigger a full table scan even with indexes on that field as it's going to check every row that matches the wildcard (everything) then it's going to return all the results. It's better to just remove the where statement.

Comment: the question about  `get a list of pages added by all users` and you pointed it already out in your comment